# Итерация циклы for трассировка

Tags: python-3.x

```
rows = range(1, 3) # range(1, 3)--> 1, 2
cols = range(1, 4)  # range(1, 4) --> 1, 2, 3
for row in rows:
    for col in cols:
        print(row, col) # --- > 1 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 3
```

Непонятно здесь, почему во втором столбце 1, 2? Берем то, что row индекс строки, col индекс столбца, `range(1, 3) range (1, 4)` -  кол-во строк и столбцов.

- 0 проход: временная переменная row берет из rows(1, 2) - 1, далее 0 итерация col временная переменная берет из cols(1, 2, 3) - 1 .
- 1 проход: временная переменная row берет из rows (1, 2) - 2?

И почему в итоге 6 столбцов? Если брать каждый цикл их по отдельности 5 получается, если только 6-ой это 0 проход(итерация).

И еще вопрос если i (временной переменной ничего не присвоено перед циклом) по умолчанию всегда с 0 начинает итерацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rows = range(1, 3) # range(1, 3)--> 1, 2
cols = range(1, 4)  # range(1, 4) --> 1, 2, 3
```

Первая итерация возьмет число `1` из `rows` и проходит дальше. Там встречается еще один цикл и этот цикл не закончится, пока не пройдет по всем трем `cols: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3`. Только после этого вы опять поднимитесь на уровень выше и возьмете следующее значение `rows` равное `2` и опять три вложенных итерации `cols: 2-1, 2-2, 2-3`. Итого получается два раза по три, всего шесть проходов.

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы поднимаетесь в своих суждениях на уровень выше до того, как выполнились все операции внутри цикла. А внутри у Вас три обязательных прохода.

---

Даже если вы что-то присвоите переменной `i` итерации все равно пойдут с нуля. Цикл `for val in iter` означает взять следующий элемент из `iter` и поместить его в `val`, только потом опускаемся к телу. И так до тех пор, пока не кончатся все элементы, по которым надо пройтись в `iter`. Поэтому даже если что-то присвоить `i`, она затрется, т.к. главные тут последовательность в самом `iter`.